# how can i change the number of columns and rows of flatlist depending on the screen orientation in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, screen-orientation

i am working on react native mobile app project, In the home screen it have 6 options, i want to show 2x3 when in portrait view and 3x2 when in landscape view

Answer (score 0):

[This Document On ScreenOrientation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/) contains all information you want